# Volatile doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, volatile

So I'm reading Brian Goetz' JCIP and wrote a following code for experimenting with `volatile` behavior.

```
public class StatefulObject {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 10;

    private volatile State state;

    public StatefulObject() {
        state = new State();
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public static class State {
        private volatile AtomicInteger counter;

        public State() {
            counter = new AtomicInteger();
        }

        public AtomicInteger getCounter() {
            return counter;
        }

        public void setCounter(AtomicInteger counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        StatefulObject object = new StatefulObject();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

        AtomicInteger oldCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger newCounter = new AtomicInteger();

        object.getState().setCounter(oldCounter);

        ConcurrentMap<Integer, Long> lastSeen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        ConcurrentMap<Integer, Long> firstSeen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        lastSeen.put(oldCounter.hashCode(), 0L);
        firstSeen.put(newCounter.hashCode(), Long.MAX_VALUE);

        List<Future> futures = IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_THREADS)
            .mapToObj(num -> executorService.submit(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    object.getState().getCounter().incrementAndGet();
                    lastSeen.computeIfPresent(object.getState().getCounter().hashCode(), (key, oldValue) -> Math.max(oldValue, System.nanoTime()));
                    firstSeen.computeIfPresent(object.getState().getCounter().hashCode(), (key, oldValue) -> Math.min(oldValue, System.nanoTime()));
                }
            })).collect(Collectors.toList());

        executorService.shutdown();

        object.getState().setCounter(newCounter);

        futures.forEach(future -> {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        System.out.printf("Counter: %s\n", object.getState().getCounter().get());
        long lastSeenOld = lastSeen.get(oldCounter.hashCode());
        long firstSeenNew = firstSeen.get(newCounter.hashCode());
        System.out.printf("Last seen old counter: %s\n", lastSeenOld);
        System.out.printf("First seen new counter: %s\n", firstSeenNew);
        System.out.printf("Old was seen after the new: %s\n", lastSeenOld > firstSeenNew);
        System.out.printf("Old was seen %s nanoseconds after the new\n", lastSeenOld - firstSeenNew);
    }
}
```

So I'm expecting that `newCounter` is always first seen only after `oldCounter` was last seen (I expect all threads to notice the update so none is referencing the stale counter). To observe this behavior I use two maps. But surprisingly, I constantly get output like this:

```
Counter: 9917
Last seen old counter: 695372684800871
First seen new counter: 695372684441226
Old was seen after the update: true
Old was seen 359645 nanoseconds after the new
```

Can you please explain where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you also explain precisely  why you expect to see newCounter only after oldCounter was been last seen.

Comment: @nos So I expect all threads to see the update so none is referencing the old counter after I updated the volatile `counter` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind your observation is not a bug in java ;) but there is one in your code. In your code you cannot guarantee that invocation of `computeIfPresent` for `lastseen` and `firstSeen` maps executed atomically (refer to the Javadocs, `computeIfPresent` is not atomic). What this means is there is time gap between when you gets `object.getState().getCounter()` and actually updates the map.

If setting `newCounter` happens while thread A in this gap (before getting the nanotime but already got the counter reference - old) and Thread B at just before getting `object.getState().getCounter()`. So if this exact moment counter reference got updated, Thread A will update the old counter key while Thread B will update the new. If Thread B took nanotime before Thread A (this could happen because these are separated threads which we cannot know what are the actual cpu scheduling) that could perfectly lead to your observation.

I think my explanation is clear. One more thing to clarify, in `State` class, you have declared `AtomicInteger counter` as volatile as well. This is not needed since a AtomicInteger is inherently is volatile. There are no "non-volatile" Atomic** s.

I just changed few things in your code to omit the above mentioned issues :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StatefulObject {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 10;

    private volatile State state;

    public StatefulObject() {
        state = new State();
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public static class State {
        private volatile AtomicInteger counter;

        public State() {
            counter = new AtomicInteger();
        }

        public AtomicInteger getCounter() {
            return counter;
        }

        public void setCounter(AtomicInteger counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        StatefulObject object = new StatefulObject();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

        AtomicInteger oldCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger newCounter = new AtomicInteger();

        object.getState().setCounter(oldCounter);

        List<Long> oldList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        List<Long> newList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        List<Future> futures = IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_THREADS)
            .mapToObj(num -> executorService.submit(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    long l = System.nanoTime();
                    object.getState().getCounter().incrementAndGet();
                    if (object.getState().getCounter().equals(oldCounter)) {
                        oldList.add(l);
                    } else {
                        newList.add(l);
                    }
                }
            })).collect(Collectors.toList());

        executorService.shutdown();

        object.getState().setCounter(newCounter);

        futures.forEach(future -> {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        System.out.printf("Counter: %s\n", object.getState().getCounter().get());
        Collections.sort(oldList);
        Collections.sort(newList);
        long lastSeenOld = oldList.get(oldList.size() - 1);
        long firstSeenNew = newList.get(0);
        System.out.printf("Last seen old counter: %s\n", lastSeenOld);
        System.out.printf("First seen new counter: %s\n", firstSeenNew);
        System.out.printf("Old was seen after the new: %s\n", lastSeenOld > firstSeenNew);
        System.out.printf("Old was seen %s nanoseconds after the new\n", lastSeenOld - firstSeenNew);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer and Thomas' one made things clear in my head :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing are not the effects of volatile but the effects of the synchronization on the `ConcurrentMap<> lastSeen`.

Let's assume that all ten threads started at about the same time. Each one does `object.getState().getCounter().incrementAndGet();` almost in parallel, thereby incrementing the `oldCounter`.

Next, those threads try to execute `lastSeen.computeIfPresent(object.getState().getCounter().hashCode(), (key, oldValue) -> Math.max(oldValue, System.nanoTime()));`. That means, they all evaluate `object.getState().getCounter().hashCode()` in parallel, each one getting the same hashcode of the `oldCounter`, then call `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent(Integer, ..)` with the same hash value.

Since all those threads try to update the value for the same key the `ConcurrentHashMap` has to synchronize these updates - only .

During the time that the first thread is updating `lastSeen` the main thread executes `object.getState().setCounter(newCounter);`, so the first thread will execute `firstSeen` for `newCounter`, while several threads are still waiting to update `lastSeen`.

---

To get better results, it would be better to separate the information gathering steps from the analyze steps.

For example, the threads could capture the counters hashcode and the timestamp of update into arrays that you analyze after all computations have been done.